# Error trying to install latest nuget pkg Aspose.Cells

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

Trying to install the latest Aspose.Cells package in VS 2019.  Had a buddy try the same thing, same error.  Have a license.  What am I missing?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Aspose.Cells.22.3.0' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'Aspose.Cells.22.3.0'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your scenario/case. I created a new console application in VS.NET 2019. Then, I clicked on Tools|Nuget Package Manager|Manage Nuget Packages… option. Now I searched Aspose.Cells (v22.3.0) after clicking Browse link. I then installed the latest version and it works fine. I do not get any error during the import process as well.

The issue might be due to NuGet Package Manager configuration on your end. You may clear NuGet cache and give it a try in your VS.NET again.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.